# Why am I getting Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am setting up webpack and react in a SpringMVC webapp and I'm getting this error when hitting my /index page.

The relevant controller method is here

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public ModelAndView index(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
```

The template at src/main/resource/templates/index.html looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Webpack App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span>React Content Below:</span>
        <div id="content"/>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/dist/app.js">
    </script>
</html>
```

Now onto the meat. My webpack.config.js looks like this

```js
// Generated using webpack-cli http://github.com/webpack-cli
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src-js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        host: 'localhost',
        port:3000
    },
    externals: {
        'react': 'React'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/preset-react',
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/,
                type: 'asset',
            },

            // Add your rules for custom modules here
            // Learn more about loaders from https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
        ],
    },
};
```

and my ./src-js/app.js looks like this.

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world</h1>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I later ammended app.js to look like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Component extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>Hello, world</h1>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

This works for now but long term I would prefer to not need to import React from this file and wrap everything in a Component.

Adding `import React from 'react'` to the top of app.js has no effect and neither does `var React = require('react')`. I'm assuming I'm just missing something in my webpack config but I can't seem to find what, anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

you can add this to **webpack.config.js**:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        React: 'react',
    }),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the webpack documentation (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) it looks like there are no quotes before the colon:

```
externals: {
    react: 'React'
},
```

A few lines below (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#object) you can find react in lowerCase:

```
externals: {
    react: 'react'
},
```

Comment: Making the changes above results in a Mininfed React Error #227. The long form of this is "ReactDOM was loaded before React. Make sure you load the React package before loading ReactDOM." I ammended the code in app.js to import React and removed the externals block entirely and now it works temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `resolve` prop here if that works for you. Like below,

```
 resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  alias: { 'react': path.resolve(__dirname), './node_modules', 'react' }
 }
```

Thus, providing the `react` module's path manually.